# How to fix type names conflicts in Dynamic Data

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

We're working in a Dynamic Data project that will handle entities coming from two different namespaces: **myModel.Abby** and **myModel.Ben**.

whose classes are:

---

**Abby**

```
myModel.Abby.Car

myModel.Abby.Lollipop
```

---

**Ben**

```
myModel.Ben.Car

myModel.Ben.Apple
```

---

So `myModel.Abby.Car` and `myModel.Ben.Car` are homonym.
when I try to register both `ObjectContext`'s, an exception is thrown telling us that there are type name conflicts between the mentioned classes (although the types belong to different namespaces).

**How can we overcome type-name conflicts, caused by repeated type names among different namespaces?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosqlprerelease/thread/39aff9f8-bdf5-4aa8-9c33-852674e5aae4)

> The problem is a naming conflict
>   between types in 2 different contexts.
>   To get around this you can rename one
>   of the classes specifying the
>   TableNameAttribute on your entity.

Hope it helps others. : )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way around this.

DynamicData routes to the correct forms based on type names. Look in the URL, the type name is always up there someplace.  How can DD know which type you mean to interact with?

Comment: Hi Jfar!
I was thinking in something like Areas or Routing by last part of namespace. +1 : )